# symfony2 problems with emacs interlock files

Tags: emacs, symfony

I've just recently started developing on Symfony 2 using Emacs.

I've encountered two places where the Emacs interlock files are interfering with Symfony 2's auto-loader functionality.

First example, when working with controllers, Emacs creates an interlock symlink file called

`.#DefaultController.php -> user@local.1234`

right next to

`DefaultController.php`

When I try to load the project in my web browser, I then get the following error:

> SplFileInfo::getMTime(): stat failed for /home/user/project/src/DefaultBundle/Controller/.#DefaultController.php

The error goes away when I manually delete `.#DefaultController.php`

Clearly, Symfony 2 is trying to stat the file and failing because it is a dead-end symlink.

Second example, when working with entities, Emacs creates an interlock symlink file called

`.#Product.php -> user@local.1234`

right next to

`Product.php`

When I try to run

`app/console doctrine:schema:update`

I then get the following error when I run app/console doctrine:schema:update

> Fatal error: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::getAllClassNames(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/user/project/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php on line 194

The error goes away after I manually remove the .#Product.php file.

Has anyone else encountered such a problem?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem about annotations reader, it should not fail so hard when a unresolvable symlink is met :

See why it fails: https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php#L194

That should be discussed on the appropriate mailing-lists with Doctrine's developers.